# JVM Heap memory usage - Heap memory usage not crossing minimum heap size

Tags: java, memory-management, heap-memory

My application heap memory usage is not increasing beyond minimum heap size. Ex : If I had set Xms as 1024 and Xmx as 2048, application memory usage is not crossing my Xms limit.

Full Garbage Collection happens whenever it reaches Xms but application memory won't increase more than Xms why?

Using IBM JDK 1.6